# How to properly execute selection in terminal - VSCode Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Sometimes I like to run my Python code line by line, in Spyder we have the F9 shortcut for this, in VSCode I tried to put this feature in the Ctrl + Enter key binding:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+enter", 
"command": "interactive.execute","when": "resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'" },
```

This kind works. It sends the lines to the terminal, but it does not execute. It seems to insert a new line right above the line codes and for this I have to manually focus the terminal and then press Enter again to execute the lines. Is this the expected behavior?

EDIT: Add image after ctrl+enter. They are not executed until I press enter in terminal
[How it looks in terminal after ctrl + enter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86MRX.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the Jupyter plugin that comes along with the MS python plugin can do for you?

Comment: Hello @JonSG. Yes, I am aware of the Jupyter plugin and indeed it would solve my problem, but I don't like it. I don't like Jupyter at all and also I think it is sluggish in VSCode.

Comment: How about highlighting the line(s) you want to run and hitting `shift + enter`?

Comment: This sends the line to the interactive Python (i.e. Jupyter), but still I would like to send the lines to the terminal, where I'm running IPython.

Comment: @alanTri Maybe you can just remove the shortcut binding to the `Jupyter Notebook`.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT, the problem is not with the key binding. My ctrl + enter is doing almost what it is supposed to do, it sends the lines to the IPython terminal to be executed. The problem is that after sending the lines, they aren't immediately executed, they keep waiting in the terminal until I focus on terminal and press enter. I was hopping for a behavior similar to F9 in Spyder: select lines, press F9, and get them straight executed in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For now, it is a know problem with IPython: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17172